# Collatz - Input Validation

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and have been following along Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. The latest project is writing a Collatz sequence, which was fairly straight forward. However, I've been unable to figure out how to add input validation through try and except.

Since try and except must be inside the loop, the error happens before that at the input stage - int(input()). However, if I add the input inside the while loop, it asks me for a new input after each cycle.

Is there a simple way of adding for and except so that when there is an invalid input, an error message shows and awaits a new input? Thanks in advance.

```
print('Hello, please input an integer.')
number = int(input())

while number != 1:
      if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        number = number // 2
      elif number % 2 == 1:
         print(3 * number + 1)
         number = 3 * number + 1
```

Comment: You need *two separate loops*, or even separate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate function that handles integer input along with validation and call it as many times you want, here:

```
def accept_int():
    while True:
        try:
            num=int(input())
            break
        except:
            print("An error occured, please re-enter!")
            continue
    return num

print('Hello, please input an integer.')
number = accept_int()

while number != 1:
      if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        number = number // 2
      elif number % 2 == 1:
         print(3 * number + 1)
         number = 3 * number + 1
```

Output:

```
$ python3 d.py 
Hello, please input an integer.
abcd
An error occured, please re-enter!
23.5
An error occured, please re-enter!
32
16
8
4
2
1
$
```

Comment: Thank so much - this is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm not sure I quite understand the additional code - while I understand what it does, I don't get how it knows to call upon the accept_int() by just entering an integer.

Comment: The function is called through "number = accept_int()" somehow, correct? Regarding output, the returned "number" becomes a global variable that is then used by my original code?

Comment: yes we return a value back from the function to the point where it was called and that value is assigned to `number`

Comment: Thanks ritesht83 - So it looks like what happens is the accept_int() is run first, which leads directly to number=int(input()), which is basically the same as your standard input function. And the "return number" is a global variable?

Comment: @ErickBrownfield nope..  `num` is a local variable to the function and available only within the function, but we pass back the value of `num` back to the caller and assign it to `number`